# First steps with Vector Bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I've concluded a differential geometry course (mainly covering classical results about parametric surfaces or diff. surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example Gauss' Theorema Egregium or geodetics) which ended with a two weeks digression over "abstract differential geometry" (basic definitions, one rapid view over some basic results, local immersion/submersion theorem and two words about vector bundles and fields...). I wanted to view something more about vector bundles and i started reading the second volume of Hatcher "Vector Bundles and K-Theory" (mainly because I liked the way Hatcher explains the ideas in the few chapter I read in his first book). But I've some problem in understanding his introduction in chapter 1. We are speaking about $TS^2$, the set of tangent spaces of $S^2$ (the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$). After equipping it with a topology (the topology of a subspace of $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^3$) he says:

> One can think of $TS^2$ as a continuous family of vector spaces $P_x$ for $x \in S^2$ parametrized by points of $S^2$.

My problem is the word "continuous", maybe is just the fact this is the first time I'm studying this kind of objects "standing alone" but I don't know how to prove this continuity or how to visualizing it.

I hope this is not a silly question, and if someone has some advices (for example, some books who treat this topic with a lower level or so on) they are greatly appreciated

Comment: By continuous he means locally trivial, i.e., a product of the fiber (in this case is a vector space of dimension $2$) and an open set (of the euclidean space) is diffeomorphic to an open neighborhood of each point in the bundle.

Comment: Hatcher´s book is an introduction to topological K-theory (that roughly speaking study the equivalence classes of vector bundles), so if you just want to learn about fiber bundles pick Steenrod´s book or Milnor´s book on characteristic classes.

Comment: $TS^2$ does not have the topology of $S^2\times\mathbb R^2$ or a subspaces of that like you said. What did you want to say there?

Comment: Typo, I mean R^3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differential structure of a smooth manifold $M$ is given by charts $\varphi: U\to\mathbb R^n$ on open sets $U\subseteq M$. These charts basically allow us to *flatten* $M$ locally. Thus, when we want a topology on $TM$, we want $TU\subseteq TM$ to be homeorphic to the tangent bundle of the flattened $\varphi(U)$
$$
TU \cong T\varphi(U) \cong \varphi(U)\times \mathbb R^n,
$$
where the tangent spaces of $\varphi(U)$ are glued together in the obvious way (since $\varphi(U)$ is just an open set in $\mathbb R^n$). Since $M$ is covered by charts and we know the topology of $TM$ over each chart, we get a topology on $TM$ by gluing the $TU$ together, again in the obvious way:
$$
TM = \left(\bigsqcup TU\right)\big/{\sim}
$$
where $\sim$ identifies the tangent spaces in $U\cap U'$ for overlapping charts.

Does this help to understand in what sense this family of tangent spaces is continuous?

---

**Update,** Another way of looking at this "continuity" in Hatchers model:

In the context of $TS^2$ as a subspace of $S^2\times\mathbb R^3$ like Hatcher introduces it, you have a tangent plane in $\mathbb R^3$ for every $x\in S^2$. If you change $x$ only by a small amount, the corresponding tangent plane will also just move by a small amount. Another way to phrase it: When $y$ approaches $x$ in $S^2$, the tangent planes at $y$ come closer and closer to tangent space at $x$.

Comment: Ok this construction surely helps. The problem was that Hatcher didn't use the word vector bundle yet and so I thought that the proof of the fact that $TS^2$ is IN FACT a vector bundle use only basic observations

Comment: To be more clear, I thought that Hatcher means there is a some kind of function $\phi : S^2 \to TS^2$ which maps each point to the tangent space in that point. And this $\phi$ is continuous

Comment: And proving this continuity was the source of my doubts

Comment: @RicPed, I added a paragraph on what Hatcher could have ment by continuity. Do you agree on this?

Comment: Agreed, all I wanted is how to prove formally your "update" without using advanced tools related to vector bundles :)

Comment: I'd say all Hatcher wants at this point is to give you a way of visualizing the topology of the tangent bundle.

Comment: Ok ok, so I try to proceed in the reading ;) thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This is just an informal quick reformulation of the formal definition, found for example in chap. 2 of Milnor+Stashef: If $X$ is a topological space, a vector bundle over $X$, say real of rank $n$, is a toplogical space $E$ and a map $p:E\to X$ such that (1) $E_x=p^{-1}(x)$ is a real vector space of dimension $n$; (2) (here comes the "continuous family of vector spaces") for every $x\in X$ there is an open set $U\subset X$ containing $x$ and a homeomorphism $p^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb R^n$ whose restriction to each $E_y$, $y\in U$, is a linear isomorphism unto $\{y\}\times\mathbb R^n$.

The standard first non-trivial  example is the tangent bundle of a differentiable manifold, where the homeomorphisms of property (2) above (called "local trivializations" of $E$) are provided by the derivatives wrt local coordinates. This is  an easy  exercise.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to "prove" about the continuity of the vector spaces involved in a vector bundle. This is essentially the content of the definition of the term "vector bundle." I believe this sentence is just an intuition building reinforcement from the author. Constructively speaking, one begins by wanting to capture the idea of vector spaces varying continuously over a space, thinks for a while, and (ideally) writes down the textbook definition that is currently used.

Comment: Ok but my problem is "how can i show that this particular family of vector fields is varying continuously"?

Comment: In other words, suppose I wanted to prove that $TS^2$ is a vector bundle, how can I proceed?

Comment: You need to check that it satisfies the definition provided.

Comment: That is, you need to find open subsets of $S^2$ and maps that trivialize the bundle over this set, as stipulated by the definition.